# Toggle custom audio play/pause button inside v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, audio

In my vue app, I have a list of audios that I created a custom audio play/pause button,

it looks like this

```
<div v-for="(post, p) in post_list">
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <v-avatar v-if="!is_played" color="#663399" size="42" class="mx-2"
        @click="playMe('custom-wave-aud-'+p)">
            <v-icon dark> mdi-play </v-icon>
     </v-avatar> 

     <v-avatar v-if="is_played" color="#663399" size="42" class="mx-2"
        @click="pauseMe('custom-wave-aud-'+p)">
            <v-icon dark> mdi-pause </v-icon>
     </v-avatar> 
</div>
```

and the function looks like this:

```
playMe(c) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(c)[0].play();
    this.is_played = true;
},
pauseMe(c) {
    document.getElementsByClassName(c)[0].pause();
    this.is_played = false;
},
```

But all the play/pause button for all audios are also toggled, I only want the played audio's button should be toggled.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You should split the codes inside the v-for into a new component called `avatar-item` for example:

```
<div v-for="(post, p) in post_list">
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <avatar-item></avatar-item>
</div>
```

Then your `avatar-item` component will look like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-avatar v-if="!is_played" color="#663399" size="42" class="mx-2"
            @click="playMe('custom-wave-aud-'+p)">
                <v-icon dark> mdi-play </v-icon>
        </v-avatar> 

        <v-avatar v-if="is_played" color="#663399" size="42" class="mx-2"
            @click="pauseMe('custom-wave-aud-'+p)">
                <v-icon dark> mdi-pause </v-icon>
        </v-avatar> 
    </div>
</template>
```

Move the variable `is_played` into this component as well as your other functions:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            is_played: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        playMe(c) {
            document.getElementsByClassName(c)[0].play();
            this.is_played = true;
        },
        pauseMe(c) {
            document.getElementsByClassName(c)[0].pause();
            this.is_played = false;
        },
    }
}

</script>
```

By this, each component will have a independent `is_played` variable, so it should be toggled independently.